# how to remove and reinstall *all* drivers on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have been having multiple blue screens recently, and I am guessing it is because of me installing unwanted drivers on my computer. I looked up this question on Google and found that sysprep is the only program that can wipe all the drivers installed, so I can reinstall them. Thank you.

Comment: There are reinstalling Windows and then only install the manufacturer's provided drivers and/or for some specific situations the drivers provided by the part/component manufacturer (updated chipset/graphics drivers and not much else really).

Comment: One way is to use sysprep.exe and choose generalize, once this is done restart the PC and drivers will reinstall automatically. Back up anything in you user account as it will be deleted.